# How to hide the left side navigation bar title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am navigating to another view controller from my current view controller in this way.

```
 ViewThingsToDoViewController *vwhings=[[ViewThingsToDoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewThingsToDoViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vwhings animated:YES];
```

after I navigate to the new view controller it shows the current view controller title in the left side. How can I hide that?

Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Didn't work anything for me. Then I tried in this way. It worked perfectly. I wanted to hide my back button title and set a title in center of my View controller navigation bar. So in viewdidload I did something like this.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title=@"";//make the left bar button title empty.
self.navigationItem.title=strNavigtionTitle;//make the centered navigation bar title.
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to combine these, so it will hide the back button even if you set it up manually

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
  self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;`

OR

`[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

the title is acting as back button... if you hide it then how will you go back.
When you navigate from ViewController **A** with title say **BASE** to ViewController **B** then navigation controller as its functionality is, sets the back button label of **B** same name as Title of **A**